# Storing a JQuery selected element as a JavaScript object property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is hopefully something very simple I am overlooking, but I am simply trying to store a JQuery reference as a property so I can reuse it more easily.

```
var debug = {
  pane: $('#debugOutput'),
  show: function() {
    debug.pane.show();
    console.log(debug.pane.length);  //0
    console.log($('#debugOutput').length);  //1
  }
}
```

The `.show()` does not work. The element is never made visible.  In the Chrome console, this is what `debug.pane` looks like:

[image]

And, of course, the actual JQuery object:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `this` instead of `debug`:

```js
let debug = {
  pane: $('#debugOutput'),
  show: function() {
    this.pane.show();
    console.log(this.pane.length);  //1
    console.log($('#debugOutput').length);  //1
  }
}

debug.show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placehold.it/300" style="display:none" id="debugOutput">
```

You can't reference `debug` in itself, since the statement defining it hasn't finished yet.

Comment: This is more of a meta question but is placehold.it the standard for example images to use in SO code? I was thinking about using another service the other day but I wasnt sure if there is a standard/prefered site.

Comment: I prefer it, there is no standard though. I was using some other service, but they dropped HTTPS for some reason, which made it impossible to be used on here...

Comment: For some reason I *cannot* get this to work and I don't know why, but it's obviously working in the snippet.  Thanks.